# how to convert a hibernate criteria query for above query?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria

```
select * from ( select * from department) d
```

how to convert a hibernate criteria query for above query?

Comment: This might be of some help -> https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tip-subquery-criteriaquery/

Comment: why don't simply `select * from department d` ?

Answer (score 0):

Extends :

```
import org.hibernate.Criteria; 
import org.hibernate.Session; 
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions; 
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
```

Create :

```
@PersistenceContext 
private EntityManager entityManager; 
public Session getSession() { 
    return (Session) this.entityManager.getDelegate(); 
}
```

and do this :

```
Criteria crit = this.getSession().createCriteria(YourClass.class); return crit.list();
```

Obs : this YourClass is the entity class

Comment: my actual question is how can i write criteria query to NESTED SQL QUERIES.pls write criteria query alone 
 CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
 CriteriaQuery<Department> criteriaQuery =criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Department.class);
 Subquery sub = criteriaQuery.subquery(Department.class); Root subRoot = sub.from(Department.class);sub.select(subRoot);   
 Root<Department> root = criteriaQuery.from(Department.class);
 criteriaQuery.from( ); Root<Project> root = criteriaQuery.from(Project.class); criteriaQuery.from( ); //stuck herequery.getResultList();

Comment: Sorry, I don`t understand what you want